# Can't install pyenv on MacOS Ventura 13.0

Tags: python, installation, pyenv

A programmer friend recommended I re-installed python on my mac using `pyenv`. I didn't understand why but given that he's much more expert than me in python I decided to trust him.

He said to do

```
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 3.10.0
pyenv global 3.10.0
```

and `brew install pyenv` worked fine, but `pyenv install 3.10.0` gave me the following error:

```
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.10.0.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.0/Python-3.10.0.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.10.0...
patching file aclocal.m4
patching file configure
patching file 'Misc/NEWS.d/next/Build/2021-10-11-16-27-38.bpo-45405.iSfdW5.rst'
patching file configure
patching file configure.ac
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 13.0 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/rp/s8k5pr4x4_z5zdp530mn99bm0000gn/T/python-build.20221109144419.49359
Results logged to /var/folders/rp/s8k5pr4x4_z5zdp530mn99bm0000gn/T/python-build.20221109144419.49359.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for python3.10... python3.10
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... "darwin"
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/rp/s8k5pr4x4_z5zdp530mn99bm0000gn/T/python-build.20221109144419.49359/Python-3.10.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

So I have two questions:

1. What advantages does `pyenv` give me?
2. How can I make it install?

Comment: Hi @beth-long, did you manage to make the install?

Comment: @HadrienHuvelle i never looked into it again until today, so no!

Answer (score 1):

**pyenv** (similar to jenv for java or nvm for NodeJS) can be installed via homebrew on the Mac: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation

1. brew install pyenv
2. Add the following lines to ~/.zprofile and ~/.zshrc:

```
##### ~/.zprofile #####
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"

##### ~/.zshrc #####
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
    eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

4. Then quit your shell session and start a new one for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I use a bash shell, what's the equivalent of the `.zshrc` line?

Comment: echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc

Comment: I did these steps, closed the terminal, reopened the terminal and did `pyenv install 3.10.0` but I got exactly the same error as before

Answer (score 0):

Im not completely sure of what the problem regarding installing this on your system may be, but I would urge you to check out [the pyenv installation guide](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation) to check if there are steps you may need to take! Check [the usage guide](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#usage) to see how it is used.

Also, you could try installing the **latest** version of 3.10 by just specifying `3.10` (not `3.10.0` which is minor version 0) instead of the minor version as well.

Regarding your question on the benefit of `pyenv`. Developers may want to use different python versions at different times because of a multitude of reasons such as package compatibility, stability, and so on. Pyenv simply gives you a simple API to easily download and use multiple python versions without having to update your PATH every time you want to use different versions of python. To quote the pyenv docs:

**What pyenv does...**

- Lets you change the global Python version on a per-user basis.
- Provides support for per-project Python versions.
- Allows you to override the Python version with an environment variable.
- Searches for commands from multiple versions of Python at a time. This may be helpful to test across Python versions with tox.

Comment: Ok, for my purposes I'm not even sure it makes a difference, but thank you for the answer. I tried `pyenv install 3.10`, and I added the `pyenv` environment variables to my `.bash_profile` as recommended in the guide, but it still won't work

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened XCode recently?  This fixed it for me.  You have to grant further permissions, and more stuff is installed, when you open XCode for the first time.

Comment: Every so often I open XCode by accident, what are the permissions and "stuff you have to install"?

Comment: Opening XCode for the first time (in a long while), I was prompted in GUI by Apple to grant permissions, but I don't recall the message content. Then a GUI install bar commenced and completed, then XCode opened for the first time. That's what I'm referring to. After I went through that, I was able to successfully install old Python versions using pyenv, whereas prior to this, even having installed the XCode developer/cli tools, I kept running into a missing zlib, and couldn't get around it with environmental variables or anything else, even though I had zlib.  Maybe nuke/reinstall XCode?